# Docker build failing- The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'

Tags: docker, nuget-package-restore, docker-build, windows-container

I am following a pluralsight tutorial- "Developing .NET Framework Apps with Docker" but dockerfile given in one of the demo failing for me.

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS builder

WORKDIR /src/PetShop.Api
COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.sln .
COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.Entities/PetShop.Api.Entities.csproj ./PetShop.Api.Entities/
COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.Model/PetShop.Api.Model.csproj ./PetShop.Api.Model/
COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.Products/PetShop.Api.Products.csproj ./PetShop.Api.Products/
COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.Products/packages.config ./PetShop.Api.Products/
RUN nuget restore PetShop.Api.sln -PackagesDirectory packages

COPY src /src
RUN msbuild PetShop.Api.Products/PetShop.Api.Products.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=c:/out


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

ENV APP_ROOT=C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot

COPY --from=builder /out/_PublishedWebsites/PetShop.Api.Products ${APP_ROOT} 
COPY --from=builder /src/PetShop.Api/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.2.1.1/build/net46/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll ${APP_ROOT}/bin

COPY config/appsettings.json ${APP_ROOT}
COPY config/logging.json ${APP_ROOT}/config/
COPY config/connectionstrings.json ${APP_ROOT}/config/
```

And here is the output of the docker build command:

```
PS C:\Users\rg21580\Downloads\docker-dot-net-framework-apps-developing\02\demos\demo3> docker build -t petshop-api ./petshop-api
    
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  94.21kB
    
    Step 1/17 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS builder
    4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019: Pulling from dotnet/framework/sdk
    
    4612f6d0b889: Already exists
                                                                                                ba8181afd426: Pull complete 
                                                                                                02ca74b83f10: Pull complete  
                                                                                               5766b0ca35fc: Pull complete  
                                                                                               ee971f2d3cad: Pull complete 
                                                                                                8bd0de32312c: Pull complete 
                                                                                                d1b79a53055d: Pull complete 
                                                                                                b9073913d17e: Pull complete 
                                                                                                6cc2f27ce166: Pull complete  
                                                                                               835d2914821b: Pull complete
                                                                                                Digest: sha256:d91ffeee472a34f8d7ff717fef54422be2ad87e59478c2e507c59eed8aaaa02e
    
    
    Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
     ---> dbbd921bf470
    Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /src/PetShop.Api
     ---> Running in 53096698fe2b
    Removing intermediate container 53096698fe2b
     ---> 0f9d67c78245
    
    Step 3/17 : COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.sln .
     ---> a119a8190c29
    
    Step 4/17 : COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.Entities/PetShop.Api.Entities.csproj ./PetShop.Api.Entities/
     ---> 0d25ee5d9c38
    
    Step 5/17 : COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.Model/PetShop.Api.Model.csproj ./PetShop.Api.Model/
     ---> 35e667754785
    
    Step 6/17 : COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.Products/PetShop.Api.Products.csproj ./PetShop.Api.Products/
     ---> 35bf8e689d58
    
    Step 7/17 : COPY src/PetShop.Api/PetShop.Api.Products/packages.config ./PetShop.Api.Products/
     ---> 67128e1c97da
    
    Step 8/17 : RUN nuget restore PetShop.Api.sln -PackagesDirectory packages
     ---> Running in c09cfa5df43b
    MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '17.1.0.7609' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin'.
    Restoring NuGet package log4net.2.0.12.
    
Restoring NuGet package Antlr.3.5.0.2.
    Unable to find version '3.5.0.2' of package 'Antlr'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
      An error occurred while sending the request.
      The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'
    
    
    The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; nuget restore PetShop.Api.sln -PackagesDirectory packages' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am unable to resolve the error- "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
An error occurred while sending the request.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org' "   which occurs at command- "RUN nuget restore PetShop.Api.sln -PackagesDirectory packages" of the docker file.Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure there isn't a network issue (like a DNS issue), then try this solution:

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/30015/1739

It helped me with the same problem.